# Properties of heat flow semigroup

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators

On a Riemannian manifold $(M^n,g)$, let $H_{B,t}^D$ be the heat flow semigroup associated with $\Delta$ and the Dirichlet boundary condition on a ball $B$, and let $h_{B,t}^D$ be its kernel. Let $h_t$ be the heat kernel on the whole manifold $M$. By which properties of heat kernel can we obtain the inequality
$$h_{B,t}^D(z,y) \le h_t(z,y) \le h_t^{1/2}(z,z)h_t^{1/2}(y,y)$$?